# Rolar a pagina verticalmente esperar e rolar de novo

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma pagina em PHP que lê um XML com uma RSS, eu gostaria de saber se há como eu rolar a pagina até aparecer a segunda RSS e depois continuar até a próxima RSS assim sucessivamente.

Veja a página: http://rss.dbcam.com.br/principais

Ao rolar vê-se outras RSS a baixo.

Outra opção seria uma forma de eu carregar a primeira RSS, depois apagar ela e aparecer a segunda e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Olá David, esse HTML do link que mostras-te está cheio de erros. Tens controlo sobre esse HTML? és tu que o crias ou é de um site externo?

Comment: sim, sou eu que tenho controle. Ele está com algumas falhas pois eu apenas estou utilizando este para exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Tens problemas no HTML que tens de corrigir.

lembra-te que IDs têm de ser unicas. Assim em vêz de

```
<div id='corpo'>
    <div id='foto'>
        <img id="foto"
```

deves usar classes e mudar para:

```
<div class='corpo'>
    <div class='foto'>
        <img class="foto"
```

No teu HTML há outro problema que é algumas divs não estarem fechadas. As divs `class="corpo"` estão a ficar dentro de si próprias.

Em relação à tua pergunta do scroll podes fazer assim, usando classes:

```
var $noticias = $('.corpo');
var qtd = $noticias.length;
var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
if ((i++) == qtd) i = 0;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $noticias.eq(i).position().top
    }, 800); // <--- velocidade do scroll

}, 2000);  // <--- tempo de espera entre cada imagem
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0ufjvuyx/